# maven: Missing library from JVM

Tags: maven, jvm, java-11

For `mvn help:describe -Dplugin=help`, I am getting:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:describe (default-cli) 
on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:describe failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:describe: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
```

It says, it cannot load a library from my JVM, which I installed via `apt`, so I guess it also installed all needed libraries?

PS: In directory `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib`, these are files with `libawt` name:

```
libawt_headless.so  libawt.so
```

cannot find the needed one `libawt_xawt.so`

`mvn -version`:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.8.0-59-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? A library installed via apt does not work.. A library which is use must be put into the pom file...

Comment: The command was issue in directory without pom file as `help:describe` target could be triggered without pom

Comment: Can you recheck the output of `mvn --version` please because the output of `mvn --version` usually looks like this: `Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)` in particular the hash in the braces...

Comment: @khmarbaise the output is as you see above, no hash in parenthesis. The `mvn` command was installed as `sudo apt-get install maven` on my ubuntu machine

Comment: Please download Maven from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi here and retest because the version you are using is not a official Maven release ... it could be a problem with the repacked version...it might be caused by that...

Comment: AWT belongs to the GUI part of Java. Make sure you have installed the full OpenJDK-11-JRE or JDK package, not the `headless` (no GUI) version.